# Display 'NULL' as string in C++

Tags: c++

Just like we display bool values as string using

> cout<<boolalpha;

which helps us printing **True** if bool value is **1** and **False** if bool value is **0**.

Is there any method like this to show `NULL` values as string in **`C++`**?

Comment: What about `std::cout << "NULL"`? There is more than one case when you can have value of `NULL`. What about `(char *) NULL` vs `(void *) NULL`?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would use this faculty (if it existed).

Comment: [`boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) is just a function. You can write whatever IO-manipulation functions you want.

Comment: `if ( !ptr ) std::cout << "NULL"; else std::cout << ptr;` ?

Comment: Or even: `std::cout << (!ptr ? "NULL" : ptr)`

Comment: I m just a noob coder, I don't know. I just wanted to know out of curiosity, if something like this existed.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Can you? I don't think it's possible to write such a manipulator without writing your own ostream class, overloading `operator << (std::ostream&, bool)` for it and doing all the magic with reassigning standard input to an object of your class.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use NULL anymore in C++. There is now type-safe version `nullptr` which is of type `nullptr_t`. And with `nullptr` you can do what you want. But it is not as useful as one might think. See code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int *p)
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}

void g(nullptr_t p)
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << nullptr << std::endl; // prints: nullptr
    f(nullptr);                        // prints: 0
    g(nullptr);                        // prints: nullptr
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `nullptr` only if the type is `nullptr_t`. So unfortunately you can't use it for every NULL pointer.

You can define an encapsulating class for printing pointers instead. Or you can use a simple condition like in comments:

```
std::cout << (!ptr ? "NULL" : ptr);
```

Comment: I assume the use-case would be more like `int* p = nullptr; std::cout << p;`, not using `nullptr` directly.

Comment: `nullptr` can be printed directly without a conversion to another pointer type only since C++17 and the result is some implementation-defined string, not necessarily `nullptr`, see https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2221.